# Python generator beginners

Tags: python

I tried this code

```
def out():
    x=0
    for line in range (x,10):
        x += 1
        return x
print out()
```

**got output result 1**

and if I tried this code

```
def out():
    x=0
    for line in range (x,10):
        x += 1
    return x

print out()
```

**Got output result 10**

But how can I got result like 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
with function

Comment: The return statement is inside the for-loop. In Python return, like any other language will return the function to it's call point. To read more on this look at the [Python Docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt) If you want a return of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` then use a variable list `list = []` and append things to it. `list.append(x)`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to make a generator.  A generator is like a function except that it yields multiple values instead of returning a single value.

```
def out():
     x=0
     for line in range(x, 10):
         x += 1
         yield x

for item in out():
    print(item)
```

Comment: I'm torn whether the idea to introduce OP to generators is a good one when he seems unable to use lists  and the return statement properly (or realize he could return a `range`).

Comment: Thanks this helps me, I try it on my code it works fine
<from time import sleep
import serial
def ser1():
    while True:
         ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 2000000)  # Establish the connection on a specific port
         counter = 32 
         counter +=1
         ser.write(str(chr(counter))) # Convert the decimal number to ASCII then send it to the Arduino
         # print ser.readline() # Read the newest output from the Arduino
         sleep(.1) # Delay for one tenth of a second
         yield ser.readline()
for item in ser1():
    print item>

Answer (score -3):

You can achieve this by putting the print statement in your loop.

Example:

```
def out():
    x=0
    for line in range (x,10):
        x += 1
        print x
```

Or if you want all the numbers on one line, you could do something like this:

```
print(" ".join(range(1,10)))
```